# Creating SAS macro to find the start month and year for a specified window

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am creating a macro for SAS that can find the beginning month and year given the specified window (in month). Appreciate if you could assist me what is wrong with the code:

```
%macro date;
%let endmonth=12;
%let endyear=2000;
%let window=24;
%if %eval(&window-12)>0
%then %do;
%if %eval(&endmonth - %eval MOD(&window,12))<0
        %then %do;
            %let startmonth=%eval(%eval MOD(&window,12)-&endmonth);
            %let startyear=%eval(&endyear-%eval(%sysevalf(&window/12,integer)-1));
        %end;
        %else %do;
            %let startmonth=%eval(&endmonth-%eval MOD(&window,12));
            %let startyear=%eval(&endyear-%sysevalf(&window/12,integer));
        %end;
%end;
%else %do;
    %if %eval(&endmonth-&window)<0
        %then %do;
            %let startmonth=%eval(&window-&endmonth);
            %let startyear=%eval(&endyear-1)
        %end;
        %else %do;
            %let startmonth=%eval(&endmonth-&window);
            %let startyear=&endyear
        %end;
    %end;
```

Comment: Are you asking for algorithm help or syntax checking. For algorithm help please explain what it is trying to do.  For syntax checking you are missing a %MEND and any code that does anything with the macro variables.  You also have way too many %EVAL() function calls.   You only need one per expression.  You don't need any around the condition being tested in %IF as SAS will imply one there.

Comment: I would like to receive algorithm help. I am currently trying to configure a SAS Macro that automatically change the starting month and year when users change the number of months of analysis, ending month and year.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  The `INTNX` function will compute all manner intervals from a given date.

Example:

```
%macro compute_start(end_ym=, months_ago=);
  %local end_dt;

  %let end_dt = %sysfunc(inputn(&end_ym.01, yymmdd8.));

  %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&end_dt,-&months_ago))
%mend;


%let start_dt = %compute_start(end_ym=200012,months_ago=24);

%put &=start_dt;

%put %sysfunc(year(&start_dt));
%put %sysfunc(month(&start_dt));

* or just;

%let start_dt = %sysfunc(intnx(
  MONTH,
  %sysfunc(inputn(20001201, yymmdd8.)),
  -24 
));
```